# Get count of values in a column and show their percentage in a plot

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

How can I count the frequency of values ​​in a column and calculate the percentage relative to the total?

I got a dataframe:

```
   range
0   G-L
1   M-R
2   G-L
3   M-R
4   A-F
5   S-Z
6   A-F
..   ..
..   ..
```

after  *df.range.value_counts()*  i get this:

```
A-F    1882
G-L    3096
M-R    3830
S-Z    1017
```

now i want to get the percentage of each range in comparison to the total sum and show this in a plot, where the x-axis got the ranges(A-F; G-L;...) und the y-axis shows the percentage of these ranges.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Where are you stucked ?

Comment: Simplify your life with `df.range.value_counts(normalize=True)` to get the %.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume this is your `DataFrame`:

```
data = {'labels': ["A-F", "G-L", "M-R", "S-Z"], 'count':[1882, 3096, 3830, 1017]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)

  labels  count
0    A-F   1882
1    G-L   3096
2    M-R   3830
3    S-Z   1017
```

Now you have to calculate the percentage of each row:

```
df['percentage'] = (df['count'] / df['count'].sum()) * 100

print(df)

  labels  count  percentage
0    A-F   1882   19.155216
1    G-L   3096   31.511450
2    M-R   3830   38.982188
3    S-Z   1017   10.351145
```

and then plot the labels vs the percentage using the `df.plot()` function and specifying its `kind`, which I assume is a barplot.

`df.plot(kind='bar', x='labels', y='percentage')`

This will produce the following plot:
[image]

**Edit:**
The `value_counts()` method returns a `pd.Series()` object. To plot it you can run the following line:

`df.range.value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar')`